# How to find which views are using a certain table in SQL Server (2008)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have to add a few columns to a table and I also need to add these columns to all the views that use this table.

Is it possible to get a list of all the views in a database that use a certain table?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE  VIEW_DEFINITION like '%YourTableName%'
```

Comment: Thanks I went with this `SELECT * 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE  VIEW_DEFINITION like '%YourTableName.%' OR VIEW_DEFINITION like '%YourTableName]%' OR VIEW_DEFINITION like '%YourTableName %'`

Comment: @James_Hill how to do the same in Oracle?

Comment: Hey downvoter, you're 5 years late to the party :-) What didn't you like?

Comment: It would improve this Answer to add a Disclaimer that this will only search the Views of the currently selected Catalog *not* the whole Databaseserver.
Took me a while to realize that...

Comment: @JamesHill Now that i think about it - yes of course. 
Maybe just add `use [Catalog]` to the Code to get people like me thinking. I suspect the stray downvoter made the same mistake.

Comment: Er, [square brackets have a special meaning in a LIKE clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql).  Example: `select 1 where 'e' like '%[YourTableName]%'`.  You should do something like `VIEW_DEFINITION like '%\[YourTableName\]%'` ESCAPE '\'

Comment: In my case to get this to work properly, I had to modify the like condition so it has no square brackets, '%MyTableName%'

Comment: Works for Mysql 5.4.x as well

Comment: It seems VIEW_DEFINITION truncates the definition as some queries I performed missed results but when using OBJECT_DEFINITION approach by Steven below I got the missing results.

Answer (score 20):

To find table dependencies you can use the sys.sql_expression_dependencies catalog view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
referencing_object_name = o.name, 
referencing_object_type_desc = o.type_desc, 
referenced_object_name = referenced_entity_name, 
referenced_object_type_desc =so1.type_desc 
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed 
INNER JOIN sys.views o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.views so1 ON sed.referenced_id =so1.object_id 
WHERE referenced_entity_name = 'Person'
```

You can also try out [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) a free SSMS and VS add-in that also has the View Dependencies feature. The View Dependencies feature has the ability to visualize all SQL database objects’ relationships, including those between encrypted and system objects, SQL server 2012 specific objects, and objects stored in databases encrypted with Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted answer could easily return wrong results, eg. if you have another table with a similar name but longer.

Comment: umm what is this magic string `Person` for ?

Comment: `Person` is just the name of the table or view you are trying to find out about.

Answer (score 7):

I find this works better:

```
SELECT type, *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%' + @ObjectName + '%'
AND type IN ('V')
ORDER BY name
```

Filtering `VIEW_DEFINTION` inside `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` is giving me quite a few false positives.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Comment: I have no affilliation with them but if you can afford to buy or have your company by SQLCompare and SQLDataCompare they are incredibly powerful products!

Comment: One thing to mention is that I'm pretty sure it doesn't search search encrypted objects

Answer (score 3):

select your table -> view dependencies -> Objects that depend on

Comment: I have found that this rarely returns accurate results.

Comment: That only returns db objects with schemabinding I believe - not all views etc. have to have this.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT VIEW_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Your Table'
```

Comment: I found out that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE is not that reliable. It should list base tables and views that a particular view is dependent on.Unfortunately, in my case (SQL 2012) at least one view was not reported as being dependent

Comment: I found out that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE is not that reliable. It should list base tables and views that a particular view is depending on.Unfortunately, in my case (SQL 2012) one view was not even present in the IS.VTU view, let alone the views/tables it was depending on. I tried to use it to determine the order views had to be re-created in, after dropping them all..

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to find used view or stored procedure for the tableName using below query -

```
exec dbo.dbsearch 'Your_Table_Name'
```