# T-SQL: sp_depends with a cursor

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, cursor

I have a bunch of Views in my DB that I would like to get the dependencies listed for.  Currently, I'm using the 'sp_depends' sproc to do this.  To speed up the process, I'm attempting to use the sp_depends sproc in a cursor that iterates over the list of views.  However, I'm not having any luck and I've spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to "shotgun" fixit.  Below is what I've got thus far.

```
DECLARE @ViewNames TABLE
(
     ViewName VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO @ViewNames
select name  from [AMF_Article].sys.views

declare @tableCursor cursor,
         @viewName varchar(100);
set @tableCursor = cursor for select ViewName from @ViewNames

open @tableCursor
fetch next from @tableCursor into @viewName
while(@@fetch_status = 0)
begin

    declare @sql varchar(max)
    set @sql = 'sp_depends ''[dbo].' + @viewName + ''
    PRINT @sql
    exec @sql

 fetch next from @tableCursor into @viewName
end
```

I think something is going on with the quoting combined with the EXEC call.  I can't get my single quotes to match up, and when I do, it still tells me no.  When I run the statement

```
sp_depends '[dbo].[V_AMF_Distinct_Products]'
```

all is well, but in a loop, not so much.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your SQL version ?

Comment: This might be helpfull,check out.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618134/how-to-find-which-views-are-using-a-certain-table-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Can you give a try with [Quotename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) in the query: `set @sql = 'sp_depends ''[dbo].' + Quotename(@viewName) + ''`

Comment: @TheGameiswar @@Version returns Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64) 
 Jun 11 2012 16:41:53 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @Arulkumar When I make that change I'm greeted with "The name 'sp_depends '[dbo].[V_Abhangers]' is not a valid identifier."  V_Abhangers is one of my Views.

Comment: Using a cursor to make this faster is one of the funniest things I have read all week. I nearly out my drink. Cursors are horribly inefficient and are a performance nightmare.

Comment: @FlexFiend: `SET @sql = 'sp_depends ' + QUOTENAME(@viewName); EXEC (@SQL)` is working in my local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside all performance considerations, take a look at slightly changed version of your script and see if it works for you:

```
DECLARE @tableCursor CURSOR
DECLARE @viewName sysname;
DECLARE @schemaName sysname; 
SET @tableCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT SS.name SchemaName, SV.name ViewName FROM sys.views SV
    JOIN sys.schemas SS ON SS.schema_id=SV.schema_id

OPEN @tableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @tableCursor INTO @schemaName, @viewName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
    SET @sql = 'sp_depends '''+QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@viewName) + ''''
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM @tableCursor INTO @schemaName, @viewName
END
CLOSE @tableCursor
DEALLOCATE @tableCursor
```

---

*Updated 16-07-2016, thanks to Sean*

To exclude cursor logic, you can also use local variable assignment like below:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)=''
SELECT @sql += 'sp_depends '''+QUOTENAME(SS.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(SV.name) + ''';'
    FROM sys.views SV
    JOIN sys.schemas SS ON SS.schema_id=SV.schema_id

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: I knew it was those awful quotes.  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: There really is no need for a cursor for this type of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this using sys.views to build your dynamic sql string. No need for cursors here.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'exec sp_depends ''' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''';'
from sys.views

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

Cursors suck :-).  Instead of executing the proc in a cursor why not just directly query what you want in a single query directly from the system tables.  The following will give you the actual script used by sp_depends:

```
sp_helptext 'sp_depends'
```

Look at the script.  Grab the select statement.  Update the select and where clause to grab what you need.  Don't accidentally overwrite or change the actual sp_depends proc or your DBA will kill you.